# Open an independent terminal window and run command with Java

Tags: java, macos, terminal, runtime

Basically, I'm trying to open a terminal window and command it to start a php script.
Also being able to input and get the output immediately when a the script output a new line to the terminal. If possible, i plan to make it `hidden`.

More like mirroring the output and input from the terminal into the java app itself

I did

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal ~/Desktop/test.php"); //mac
```

I have no idea how to input and get output immediately once the php script sends an output to the terminal.

Please do help me here

Comment: General tips:  1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.  2) Ask a question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson if the script was asking for more input, how would i do so?

Comment: Not sure on that one, but look at the I/O streams offered by the `Process`.

Answer (score 0):

create process and read input stream of process.

(javadoc) getInputStream()

Gets the input stream of the subprocess. The stream obtains data piped from the standard output stream of the process represented by this Process object.

```
//-->check command line<--
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/php /home/amit/hello.php");
BufferedInputStream iStream = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
BufferedOutputStream oStream = new BufferedOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (true){
   int length = iStream.read(buffer);
   if(length == -1)
      break;
   System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, length));
}
```

Note: have written with respect to Linux.

Comment: i tried `System.out.println(stream.read());` but either than the script running, nothing is printing on the original terminal?

Comment: You should use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), not Runtime.exec. See Andrew Thomson's comment to question to see the link why shouldn't you use Runtime.exec.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing the php script in the terminal, which in turns uses php to execute the script, just execute the php script in php and capture the input/output.

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```